# Program for converting a boring text into a stylish written text

Tags: java

I have written a program that makes it possible to write as cool as the cool kids. All you have to do is enter the boring, normal text, which is then transformed into an exciting, stylish text.
Is there a possibilty to make the code more performant without decreasing it's readability?

**Example Output:**

I H@Ve wRITTen @ Pr0qR@M tH@T m@KEZ IT P0ZzIblE t0 wriTE @z C00L @z the c00L KIdZ :) All Y0U h@Ve T0 D0 iZ eNter thE B0rinQ, n0rm@L teXt, whIch iZ tHeN TR@nZF0RmED int0 @n exCiTInq, ztyLIZh TExT. :D

**Source code**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String text = input.nextLine();
        String trendyText = convertToTrendyText(text);
        System.out.println(trendyText);
    }

    public static String convertToTrendyText(String string) {
        string = string.replace("g", "q");
        string = string.replace("s", "z");
        string = string.replace("a", "@");
        string = string.replace("o", "0");
        string = string.replace(". ", " " + generateRandomSmiley() + " ");
        string = string.replace("! ", " " + generateRandomSmiley() + " ");
        string = string.replace("? ", " " + generateRandomSmiley() + " ");
        string = string.concat(" " + generateRandomSmiley());

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(string);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                text.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(i)));
            }
        }

        return text.toString();
    }

    public static String generateRandomSmiley() {
        Random random = new Random();

        switch (random.nextInt(10)) {
            case 0: return ":)";
            case 1: return ":D";
            case 2: return ":*";
            case 3: return "<3";
            case 4: return "o.O";
            case 5: return "x3";
            case 7: return "xD";
            case 8: return ":o";
            default: return ";D";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Cough* The cool kids write in Times New Roman font size 12. JK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally. A program to help me speak the same language as the cool kids. Thanks for that.

#### Use an array when it's good enough

The second part of `convertToTrendyText` needlessly uses a `StringBuilder` instance.
The power of `StringBuilder` is to efficiently build strings whose size is not known in advance.
In this method we *do* know in advance,
so there's no need for a `StringBuilder`,
an array from `string.toCharArray()` would be more than enough.
After replacing characters in the `char[]`,
you could return it in a `new String(...)`.

#### Destructive uppercasing

The first part of `convertToTrendyText` inserts some random smileys.
The second part of the method randomly uppercases some letters.
That risks ruining the following smileys: `o.O`, `x3`, `xD`.
I'm wondering if that's intended or not.
With this potential unintended side effect,
the text might become completely unreadable.

To avoid such destruction,
you could swap the first and second parts:
do the uppercasing first,
and insert smileys after.
That way the smileys will be unaffected by design.

#### One `Random` is enough

There's no need to create multiple instances of `Random` in a program.
It would be better to use just one.
That could be a good step in the direction of making the program testable,
because you will be able to set a seed to get reproducible output.

#### Getting a random value out of `n` values

The `switch` statement in `generateRandomSmiley` is a bit troublesome.
If you add a new smiley, you have to remember to increment the number in the `random.nextInt(...)` call, and add a correctly numbered `case` statement. Such a hassle.

If you use an array of smileys,
then the process of adding or removing values becomes a lot simpler,
more compact,
without having to worry about indexes.

```
private static final String[] SMILEYS = {
    ":)", ":D", ":*", "<3", "o.O", "x3", ";D", "xD", ":o", ";D"
};

public static String generateRandomSmiley() {
    return SMILEYS[random.nextInt(SMILEYS.length)];
}
```

Btw, did you notice that there is no `case 6` line in your original `switch` statement?
That leads to getting the same value for it as the `default` case.
Not sure if that was intentional.
To preserve the behavior of the posted code,
I duplicated the default value `;D` at index `6` (in addition to its natural index `9`).

#### A word on performance

Every call like `string = string.replace("...", "...");` has to iterate over all the content of the string.
That seems a bit wasteful.
In a toy program like this,
it doesn't really matter,
but it's worth keeping in mind.